# Regex to extract data in between string

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, uipath

Ive tried the ff regex below but it does not seem to work. I wanted to extract data between F. Prepaids and G. Initial Escrow Payment and get the ff sample result below. Thanks.

#my regex

```
(?<=F. Prepaids)[\S\s]*?(?= G. Initial Escrow Payment)
```

#String

```
F. Prepaids $887.01
01 Homeowner's Insurance Premium ( 12 mo.) toAmerican Family  $893.00
Insura
02 Mortgage Insurance Premium (     mo.)
03 Prepaid Interest ($5.99 per day from 10/02/2020 to 10/01/2020) -$5.99
04 Property Taxes (     mo.)
05
06
07
08
G. Initial Escrow Payment at Closing $3,776.11
```

If i got the data in between I also want a regex to get the ff result which other data includes new lines based on the strin above.

```
Homeowner's Insurance Premium ( 12 mo.) to American Family Insura
Mortgage Insurance Premium ( mo.)
Prepaid Interest ($5.99 per day from 10/02/2020 to 10/01/2020)
Property Taxes (     mo.)
```

Any idea with this one ? Thnk you.

Comment: To get the content in between, omit the space before G.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: There is a space in the lookahead before the G. see https://regex101.com/r/n6PgvI/1

Comment: Use `(?<=F. Prepaids)[\S\s]*?(?=G. Initial Escrow Payment)`

Comment: and how do i get the ff result below ? like the Homeowner's Insurance Premium ( 12 mo.) to American Family Insura

Comment: What do you mean by `ff result`? Do you want to get those lines from the same example data without the leading numbers. The lines in the second example are not exactly the same as in the first example.

Comment: Homeowner's Insurance Premium ( 12 mo.) to American Family Insura
Mortgage Insurance Premium ( mo.)
Prepaid Interest ($5.99 per day from 10/02/2020 to 10/01/2020)
Property Taxes (     mo.)

Comment: please check above

Comment: that format... Sikr

Comment: Try [this regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%28%3f%3c%3dF%5c.+Prepaids.*%5cn%5b%5cs%5cS%5d*%3f%29%5e%5cd%2b+%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%5b%5cs%5cS%5d*%3f%5cnG%5c.+Initial+Escrow+Payment%29&i=F.+Prepaids+%24887.01%0d%0a01+Homeowner%27s+Insurance+Premium+%28+12+mo.%29+toAmerican+Family++%24893.00%0d%0aInsura%0d%0a02+Mortgage+Insurance+Premium+%28+++++mo.%29%0d%0a03+Prepaid+Interest+%28%245.99+per+day+from+10%2f02%2f2020+to+10%2f01%2f2020%29+-%245.99%0d%0a04+Property+Taxes+%28+++++mo.%29%0d%0a05%0d%0aG.+Initial+Escrow+Payment+)

Comment: Sir @WiktorStribiżew this is my new problem Sir , might you have an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64026623/regex-to-extract-data-that-includes-next-lines

Comment: It is the same issue I believe. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?m)(?<=F\. Prepaids[\s\S]*?^\d+ )[^\r\n]+(?:\r?\n[^\n\d][^\r\n]*)?(?=[\s\S]*?\nG\. Initial Escrow Payment)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%28%3f%3c%3dF%5c.+Prepaids%5b%5cs%5cS%5d*%3f%5e%5cd%2b+%29%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%5b%5e%5cn%5cd%5d%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d*%29%3f%28%3f%3d%5b%5cs%5cS%5d*%3f%5cnG%5c.+Initial+Escrow+Payment%29&i=F.+Prepaids+%24887.01%0d%0a01+Homeowner%27s+Insurance+Premium+%28+12+mo.%29+toAmerican+Family++%24893.00%0d%0aInsura%0d%0a02+Mortgage+Insurance+Premium+%28+++++mo.%29%0d%0a03+Prepaid+Interest+%28%245.99+per+day+from+10%2f02%2f2020+to+10%2f01%2f2020%29+-%245.99%0d%0a04+Property+Taxes+%28+++++mo.%29%0d%0a05%0d%0aG.+Initial+Escrow+Payment+)

**Details**

- `(?m)` - multiline mode on
- `(?<=F\. Prepaids[\s\S]*?^\d+ )` - match a location immediately preceded with `F. Prepaids`, then any zero or more chars as few as possible, then 1+ digits at the start of a line and then a space
- `[^\r\n]+` - any one or more chars other than CR and LF and
- `(?:\r?\n[^\n\d][^\r\n]*)*` - zero or more sequences of CRLF or LF ending, any non-digit and non-newline char and then any zero or more chars other than a newline and carriage return
- `(?=[\s\S]*?\nG\. Initial Escrow Payment)` - the current location must be followed with

  - `[\s\S]*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
  - `\n`  - a newline
  - `G\. Initial Escrow Payment` - a  `G. Initial Escrow Payment` text.

Comment: but there is a text being attach which is on the nextline for example for the first number the output should be " Homeowner's Insurance Premium ( 12 mo.) to American Family Insura "  , which insura is on the nextline and the money $893.00 was removed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64026623/regex-to-extract-data-that-includes-next-lines

Comment: can we try it on regex 101 website ?

Comment: @MrDave You can't match discontinuous texts within one match operation. This is all you can do with a single match/extract option. No, regex101 does not support .NET syntax.

Comment: how do we remove $893.00 from a string ? like what is a regex to remove for example money like $893.00

Comment: cause I wanted to achieve this output Homeowner's Insurance Premium ( 12 mo.) to American Family Insura

Comment: @MrDave *You can't match discontinuous texts within one match operation.*. Or use replace. Have you tried using replace?

Comment: Yeah , how do we do it in replace ? I can implement that

Comment: after using your regex above we will then use replace

Comment: how do we do it using replace Sir ?

Comment: Like [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.*%29%5cs%5c%24%5cd%5b%5cd.%5d*%28%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d*%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!%5cd%2b+%29%28.%2b%29%29%3f&i=Homeowner%27s+Insurance+Premium+%28+12+mo.%29+toAmerican+Family++%24893.00%0d%0aInsura&r=%241%242%243).

Comment: @MrDave I have no idea what "does not seem to work" mean. As you see in my demo, from `Homeowner's Insurance Premium ( 12 mo.) toAmerican Family  $893.00\r\nInsura` string, you get the `Homeowner's Insurance Premium ( 12 mo.) toAmerican Family Insura` string,